# Why am I getting a dot(period symbol) that is leading each string/value in my program using Apache POI?

Tags: java, file-io, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI for the first time to read and store data from an excel file. [here's an example of what is happening when I run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqfG7.png)

There should not be any dots in front of the names. 
Also, for some of the states, since the values in the excel file are really large, it is showing:

```
The data from year 2010 to 2017 for .New York is: [1.9405185E7, 1.9526372E7, 
1.9625409E7, 1.9712514E7, 1.977358E7, 1.9819347E7, 1.9836286E7, 1.9849399E7]
```

Can I use BigDecimal to get around this? If so I'm not really sure how. My code for this program is

```
public class PopulationEval {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
         InvalidFormatException 
    { 
        File excelFile = new 
        File("C:\\Users\\gg\\Documents\\2017census.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excelFile);

        XSSFWorkbook myWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

        XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator();

        int selectedRow = 1;
        HashMap GeographicArea = new HashMap();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            int selectedColumn = 1;

            ArrayList yearlyData = new ArrayList();

            String geographicName = "";
            while(cellIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch(cell.getCellType())
                {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        double num = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        if(selectedColumn !=1 && selectedRow >=3)
                        {
                            yearlyData.add(num);
                        }

                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        String stringValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        //System.out.print(stringValue );
                        if(selectedRow >= 3 && selectedColumn == 1)
                        {
                            geographicName = stringValue;
                        }
                        if(selectedColumn != 1 && selectedRow >= 3)
                        {
                            yearlyData.add(stringValue);
                        }
                        break;

                }
                selectedColumn++; 
            }
            if(!geographicName.isEmpty())
            {
                GeographicArea.put(geographicName, yearlyData);
            }
            //System.out.println();
            selectedRow++;
        }


        fis.close();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Which state would you like to view data for from 
        2010 to 2017? Use proper spelling.");
        String user = input.nextLine();

            if(GeographicArea.containsKey(user))
            {
                System.out.println("The data from year 2010 to 2017 for " + 
                user + " is: " + GeographicArea.get(user));
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by rounding here ? Here -> Can I use BigDecimal to get around this?

Comment: I'm saying how can I avoid getting that 'E7' in there with the numbers

Comment: please check the answer!

Comment: You are getting lots of compiler warnings all over the place, and you would be wise to heed them. In particular, that `HashMap` is a `Map<String, Something>`, and what "something" is matters very much for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this utility method whenever you want to round your double:

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(value));
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

And in your program when you're adding the double value into the list, wrap that within this method call and provide the "places" as follows:

> yearlyData.add(round(num,5));

Comment: Just use `printf`.